# view html page inside another html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how can i include html page inside another html 
since i don't use any server side languages, I just want to make it through html and css.
I want to click over anchor and then display the html in the center div of the page, since i devide the html page to header, footer, and body.

Comment: use <iframe> maybe, <frameset> could be used too. But these way to create webpages is really old.

Comment: I don't think <iframe> make what i want!

Comment: If you don't want to reload the page Javascript and a serverside language are necessary.

Comment: You say that you don't use server side languages -- do you use Javascript?

Comment: yes, I want to use java script

Comment: @starcorn- I totally agree they are very old fashion.

Comment: you will want to use ajax. it will allow your javascript to request a page, and put the returned content in whatever element you want, without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery to fetch the HTML page from the server and set its contents within the desired `div`.  Just bind it to the anchor's click event, something like this:

```
$('#myanchor').click(function() {
    $.get('mypage.html', function(data) {
        $('#mydiv').html(data);
    });
});
```

(Note that this is freehand code, I haven't tested it.  But you get the idea.)

Comment: I don't want to call the page through server, I just want to reder it. Can u rewrite ur code through js not jquery?

Comment: @David This should work, but the mixture of jQuery and `href="javascript:` is unorthodox at best...

Comment: @lonesomeday: True, it was a rush job.  Better to bind to the click event.  Mixing markup and code is never good.  Code updated.

Comment: @Alaa: If you're not getting the page from the server, where are you getting it from?  Also, jQuery _is_ JavaScript.

Comment: It's just case of rendering html pages inside each other. It's not a real website ,but just for learning .

Comment: @Alaa: This should do just that.  This code would be put on Page A, which would load the contents of Page B (referred to as mypage.html in the example) into a div on Page A (referred to as #mydiv in the example) when an anchor is clicked (referred to as #myanchor in the example).  No server-side code necessary.  I'm assuming that the two pages (one rendering inside the other) are separate files on the server.